# How to modify data for a SugarCRM SubPanel using PHP?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Is there anyway to modify the content shown in a SugarCRM Subpanel without relying on Action Hooks?

Right now to edit content for a Subpanel field I have to use the hooks like this...

`$hook_array['process_record']`

And in the Class method that I assign the Hook to call I can then change a field in the Subpanel like this...

```
$bean->name = '<a href="/index.php?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Fmodule%3Dproje_Web_Project_Tasks%26action%3DDetailView%26record%3D'
.$bean->id.'" rel="popover" data-content="'
.$bean->description.'" data-original-title="">'.$bean->name.'</a>';
```

The main and major problem we have with this method is it works great until you do either of these actions....

1. Add an item using the Quick Create form
2. Change a page using the Subpanel paging buttons

In either case, it reloads the Subpanel data without running this hook code on the data, so the result is pretty major as the Subpanel fields that you have edited are no longer edited and show up as normal.

Here is a basic example...this shows 2-3 fields that have been edited using the Hook method above...
[image]

Now after paging or quick-creating a new record in the Subpanel, it reloads the Subpanel data and does not apply the Hooked code so you can see the result looks like this...
[image]

I know that `ListView` has a much more reliable and flexible method for editing it's content using the `get_list_view_data()` method I am able to apply the same edits and have them work all the time!

So I am hoping there is a similar method to edit Subpanel data and have it always apply the edits to that data?  From what I have seen in my research so far, the only solution that will work as expected all the time, is to make a completely new `Custom Field Type`!

I am really hoping that is not the ONLY way as that is a major pain to do that for each type of field that I need to edit in the Subpanels and just doesn't feel right when there are easy ways to edit everything else except SubPanel data.

Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions, tips, help, please do share with me on this matter as it is the main problem I have had since I started developing with SugarCRM in the past few months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the data by writing a custom query to get data for your subpanel.

So inside your bean (this case Contacts) do a functions:

```
function get_project_list() {
   $query = "SELECT project, info, matching, column, names FROM projects WHERE contact_id = '" . $this->id . "' AND deleted = 0"
   return $query;
}
```

and then in subpanel definition set the data source like this:

```
$layout_defs["Contacts"]["subpanel_setup"]['projects'] = array(
        'order' => 10,
        'sort_order' => 'desc',
        'sort_by' => 'name',
        'title_key' => 'LBL_PROJECTS_TITLE',
        'subpanel_name' => 'contact_projects',
        'module'=>'projects',
        'get_subpanel_data' => 'function:get_project_list',
        'function_parameters'=>array('type'=>'urgent'), // this is optional if you decide to sent parameters to the function if do this dont forget to define your function with function get_project_list($params)
        'top_buttons' => array (... buttons that you need go here..),
);
```

Since sql is quite powerful you can modify your subpanel data any way you like, well more or less :)

Comment: This was not actually what I was trying to achieve in my original question as I did not need to alter the data result but simply alter the way it appeared.  However on a new project for a different task, this answer is exactly what I need!  Thanks

Comment: IN your example it assumes that the subpanel has already been added using module builder or studio.  DO you know how to use your method when the subpanel does not even exist yet?  Meaning to use code to add the subpanel and then use your technique to alter the data source?  I have found many conflicting articles that are all slightly different it seems!